# Use @dynamic to acknowledge intention

Tags: objective-c

I was under the impression that this was the correct pattern for declaring a `readonly` property in a base class and make it `readwrite` in a child class. I think I've even done something similiar before, so I'm probably missing something.

```
// Signal.h
@interface Signal : NSObject
@property (readonly) NSUInteger version;
@end

@interface MutableSignal : Signal
@property (readwrite) NSUInteger version;
@end
```

And my .m file:

```
// Signal.m
@interface Signal () {

    @protected
    NSUInteger _version;
}
@end

@implementation Signal

@synthesize version = _version;

- (NSUInteger)version
{
    @synchronized (self) {
        return _version;
    }
}

@end

@implementation MutableSignal

- (void)setVersion:(NSUInteger)version
{
    @synchronized (self) {
        _version = version;
    }
}

@end
```

I get the following warning on the `readwrite` declaration, under `MutableSignal`:

> Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'version'; it will be implemented by its superclass, use @dynamic to acknowledge intention

I tried adding `@dynamic` in the implementation, but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you post your code with `@dynamic`? Adding that silences the warning for me.

Comment: I put it int the `Signal` implementation, instead of `@synthetise`. Where did you put it?

Comment: Ok, I see now. It must be in the mutable implementation

Comment: If that fixes the problem for you, it'd be nice to post it as an answer.

Comment: I was expecting you to, but I see you have plenty of rep :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use `@dynamic` in the `MutableSignal` implementation, instead of `Signal`.